# How to load a RAW image file with CoreImage using CIRawFilter?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-image

I'm trying to load a RAW file from a camera (in DNG format in this instance) into a `CIRawFilter` in order to apply adjustments to it. However, I can't successfully load the file into the CI filter. I'm currently trying this in an Xcode playground so perhaps that's the issue, but the code I'm using is:

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation
import CoreImage

// Returns "/var/folders/8_/b823wmf15sz1445g07z22nw00000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/resources/4EB47089-747B-4F7D-89F2-EE815F5C2F1F/rawSource.DNG"
let rawSourcePath = Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "DNG", inDirectory: nil)[0]
// rawFilter is nil
let rawFilter = CIRAWFilter(imageURL: URL(string: rawSourcePath))
```

`rawSourcePath` appears to return a valid file path pointing to the file that's in the playground `Resources` folder, but trying to initialize `rawFilter` with it just results in a `nil` value. Does anyone know how to load the RAW file into a `CIRawFilter`? There's next to no example documentation on it anywhere that I can find.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the incorrect way you are creating the `URL` instance. Since `rawSourcePath` is a file path and not a URL you must change your code to:

```
let rawSourcePath = Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "DNG", inDirectory: nil)[0] // Unchanged
let rawFilter = CIRAWFilter(imageURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: rawSourcePath)) // Note changed URL initializer
```

Even better is to use:

```
let rawSourceURL = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "DNG", subdirectory: nil).first! // Crash if there are no DNG files
let rawFilter = CIRAWFilter(imageURL: rawSourceURL)
```

Comment: I tried this but instantiating the `CIRawFilter` just returns `"Error: Invalid string"`.

Comment: So the problem you posted is resolved and you have now moved onto a new issue.

Comment: I don't think so? The issue I posted about regarded how to load a RAW file into a `CIRawFilter`.